# Can't push to github in ssh terminal session (Ubuntu ssh-agent over ssh)

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh, ssh-agent

Sometimes I forget to push something to github on my home computer, so I quickly log into it using SSH and push it then. But I always get this error:

```
$ git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have X11 forwarding turned on, but that's it! Why is it complaining about the publickey when it simply works when I'm at home?

The github repository is this one:
git@github.com:skerit/alchemy.git

It also only fails to work with github. Other, private repositories work just fine.

My workaround now is to create a vnc session and push it like that, but that's annoying.

**Edit1:**

Ubuntu's ssh-agent seems to be bound to the Unity session somehow, and any process not being spawned from there on out can not access it. Which is annoying.

```
 3123 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

**Edit2:**

I found a way to use the existing ssh-agent, and while it does load in the existing keys, it STILL does not work.

https://superuser.com/questions/141044/sharing-the-same-ssh-agent-among-multiple-login-sessions

Answer (score 0):

If your "not-at-home" machine has your SSH keys and an agent running you can use agent-forwarding when connecting to your home machine. Try ssh option `-A` or set `ForwardAgent` to `Yes`. See `man ssh` and `man ssh_config` for further details.